# Check if any related record exists in any other tables - Yii 2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, foreign-keys

Is there any way to check all the other tables to find if any record exists that has a foreign key relationship with one particular table. Please give suggestions if there is any out of the box method in yii2. 
purpose is to check if related data exists, then dont delete, but has to be done through code(without setting restrict on delete in db). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple way, try to delete related record using `delete()` and catch the exception.

Comment: But it can done only if we have set ondelete- restrict in relation . right?

Comment: yes, you were right.